# how to match with like in other table and count

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

i have 2 tables
areas2013

```
row_id | area              |teamleader
1      |  1234-Asia        |   Joe 
2      |  12345-Europe     |   Juan  
3      | 123456-UK         |   Ple
```

and
f12

```
row_id| eacode
1     | 1234
2     | 12345
3     | 1234
```

as you can see i want to match the eacode and area using like% and count how many eacode.

i want something like this in php

```
eacode| area | count | teamleader 
1234  | Asia  |   2    |  Joe
12345 | Europe|   1    |  Juan
```

sorry for my bad english

Comment: Can you please set up an sql fiddle with your schema and data http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: I don't see the matching. `f12` doesn't have `12345`.

Comment: sorry i forgot the 3 i'll edit it

Comment: You should optimize your table. Make two columns for this values: '1234-Asia' ...

Comment: i cant change the structure of the database. i think i will use explode and separate -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barmar's answer is good I just tweaked it a bit to get the exact output you requested:

```
SELECT eacode, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(area, '-', 2), '-', -1) as area, count(*) `count`, teamleader
FROM f12
JOIN areas2013 ON area like CONCAT(eacode, '-%')
GROUP BY eacode
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT eacode, substr(area, locate('-', area) + 1) area, count(*) `count`, teamleader
FROM f12
JOIN areas2013 ON area like CONCAT(eacode, '-%')
GROUP BY eacode
```

Comment: i want to count the eacode in f12 and display the teamleader and area in the other table

Comment: That's what this does, using the join. I assume there's only one matching row in `areas2013`, is that incorrect?

Comment: Why did you unaproved Barmar answer? Here is a working SQLFiddle for Barmar code: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa8ef/1