# MySql select like where field like full string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a site that uses the same code for several websites, each site is dynamically different from the other based on settings in the products table.

When a user hits the site, I grab the full URL, I have a short version of the url in the products table URL field.

I need to know what product he has loaded, so effectively I need to say

```
WHERE %URL% like fullURL
```

where url is the smaller URL and full URL is the URL of the page he loaded.

For example, in the products tbl I could have URL `blog.com`
user hits the page and the full URL pulled is `www.blog.com/index.php?parm1=test`

so I would need

```
WHERE %www.blog.com% like www.blog.com/index.php?parm1=test
```

Here is the code, any assistance is greatly appreciated

```
$pageURL = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE %URL% like '".$pageURL."'";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to match with like in other table and count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17344504/how-to-match-with-like-in-other-table-and-count)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `INSTR()` method.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE INSTR('".$pageURL."%',url) > 0";
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I want to say (: +1

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM products
        WHERE '$pageURL' LIKE CONCAT('%', url, '%')";
```